# Android Spinner Exception when clicked BadTokenException

Tags: android, spinner, popupwindow

I have a problem when clicking on a spinner ( in a popup window )

here is my popup:

```
public class PopupDialog extends PopupWindow  {

    public PopupDialog() {
        super();
        init();
    }

    public PopupDialog(View contentView, int width, int height) {
        super(contentView, width, height);
        init();
    }

    public PopupDialog(View contentView) {
        super(contentView);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        this.setTouchable(true);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());

        this.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    PopupDialog.this.dismiss();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

the click of the button that shows the popup:

```
public void click(View v) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
         = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
          .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
                 final PopupDialog popupWindow = new PopupDialog(
                   popupView, 
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                 popupWindow.setHeight(metrics.heightPixels);
                 popupWindow.setWidth(300);

                 popupWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, v.getLeft()+v.getWidth(), 0);

    }
```

I have this exception ( BadTokenException )

```
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@410ad298 is not valid; is your activity running?
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:515)
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:279)
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:988)
05-29 16:35:10.627: E/AndroidRuntime(1055):     at and
```

Any help is welcome, thank you in advance :)

Comment: have you tried after changing  `LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
         = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
          .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`  to         `LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
         = (LayoutInflater)v.getContext()
          .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);` ?

Comment: same issue when I changed to LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)v.getContext() .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a context conflict. Try adding this in your XML spinner declaration : `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`

Comment: yes thanks, It's working fine on dialog mode, but I must do it in dropdown mode , do you have any idea of what to change to achieve this in dropdown mode?

Comment: In my opinion it's not possible, since the popupWindow takes over the focus on your activity.

Comment: I don't know but with the number of tries and the number of hours spent to achieve it, I m sure your right when you say that's impossible :D
thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Do a test here,

Remove temporarily this part of your code

```
 this.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    PopupDialog.this.dismiss();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

and check.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not too late.
I had the same issue. Things were working fine with

```
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
```

However, I was unable to achieve a dropdown (without dialog popup) with the PopupWindow.
I got the same working by using *alertbuilder* instead.

You can follow this tutorial:
[YT Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlqtyfshUkc)